# The enveloping algebra of a finite dimensional Lie algebra has no zero divisor

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a complex, finite dimensional Lie algebra.

It is well-known that the graded associative algebra of the enveloping algebra $U(L)$ is isomorphic to the symmetric algebra $S(L)$. Therefore $U(L)$ has no non-zero zero-divisors.

But I really want to know is: can we prove this without the Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi: can you suggest a reference where I can read about the well-known fact?

Comment: HI: I read the book: <<Lie groups beyond an introduction>> 2ed by Anthony W. Knapp;   page.223, proposition 3.16.